# How can a "grep | sed | awk" script merging line pairs be more cleanly implemented?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

I have a little script to extract specific data and cleanup the output a little. It seems overly messy and i'm wondering if the script can be trimmed down a bit.

---

- The input file contains of pairs of lines -- names, followed by numbers.
- Line pairs where the numeric value is not between 80 and 199 should be discarded.
- Pairs may sometimes, but will not always, be preceded or followed by blank lines, which should be ignored.

**Example input file:**

```
al12t5682-heapmemusage-latest.log
38

al12t5683-heapmemusage-latest.log
88
al12t5684-heapmemusage-latest.log
100
al12t5685-heapmemusage-latest.log
0

al12t5686-heapmemusage-latest.log
91
```

**Example/wanted output:**

```
al12t5683 88
al12t5684 100
al12t5686 91
```

**Current script:**

```
grep --no-group-separator -PxB1 '([8,9][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9])' inputfile.txt \
  | sed 's/-heapmemusage-latest.log//' \
  | awk '{$1=$1;printf("%s ",$0)};NR%2==0{print ""}'
```

**Extra input example**

```
al14672-heapmemusage-latest.log
38

al14671-heapmemusage-latest.log
5

g4t5534-heapmemusage-latest.log
100

al1t0000-heapmemusage-latest.log
0
al1t5535-heapmemusage-latest.log
al1t4676-heapmemusage-latest.log
127

al1t4674-heapmemusage-latest.log
53

A1t5540-heapmemusage-latest.log
54

G4t9981-heapmemusage-latest.log
45

al1c4678-heapmemusage-latest.log
81

B4t8830-heapmemusage-latest.log
76

a1t0091-heapmemusage-latest.log
88

al1t4684-heapmemusage-latest.log
91
```

**Extra Example expected output:**

```
g4t5534 100
al1t4676 127
al1c4678 81
a1t0091 88
al1t4684 91
```

Comment: "Ignore the numbers in the servername lines" doesn't make sense here -- your sample output still has numbers in it. Please try to be sure the textual description and the example are consistent.

Comment: thanks cyrus
Charles, i was trying to explain that the script/code should not search for the number ranges within the servername area.

Comment: If it's not *always* every 3rd row, you should ensure your sample input only sometimes contains the extra whitespace.

Comment: Ahh, I see how that happened -- if you look at the original post at https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/82717234-daa2-49d7-854c-f5283e33dfdf, the way the site rendered it merged the linebreaks, so that was my editing trying to infer where you *really* wanted them to be and getting it wrong; what you really wanted was for the source to look equivalent to the relevant section of https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/82717234-daa2-49d7-854c-f5283e33dfdf/view-source.

Comment: Your "extra input example" should still be paired with sample output. Right now, we don't know what output should be in the two-names-one-number case.

Comment: The new extra output doesn't line up with the extra input -- for example, the "extra output" contains a `a1t0091 88`, but there's no `88` in the input at all.

Answer (score 3):

Consider implementing this in native bash, as in the following (which can be seen running with your sample input -- including sporadically-present blank lines -- at http://ideone.com/Qtfmrr):

```
#!/bin/bash
name=; number=
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line ]] || continue                       # skip blank lines
  [[ -z $name ]] && { name=$line; continue; }   # first non-blank line becomes name
  number=$line                                  # second one becomes number
  if (( number >= 80 && number < 200 )); then
    name=${name%%-*}                            # prune everything after first "-"
    printf '%s %s\n' "$name" "$number"          # emit our output
  fi
  name=; number=                                # clear the variables
done <inputfile.txt
```

The above uses no external commands whatsoever -- so whereas it might be slower to run over large input than a well-implemented `awk` or `perl` script, it also has far shorter startup time since no interpreter other than the already-running shell is required.

See:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) - *How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?*, describing the `while read` idiom.
- [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) - *How do I do string manipulations in bash?*; or [The Bash-Hackers' Wiki on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), describing how `name=${name%%-*}` works.
- [The Bash-Hackers' Wiki on arithmetic expressions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr), describing the `(( ... ))` syntax used for numeric comparisons.

Comment: this also seems to miss some values, possible due to my edit failure mentioned in above comments

Comment: Indeed, that's a critical distinction (so is that those blank lines are only *sometimes* present -- the much shorter/easier revision to handle them just adds a `&& read blank` to the `while` loop and thus assumes they'll always be there). See this answer as-edited working at https://ideone.com/5AhkTX

Comment: In awk this would be a one-liner, in bash it is so huge, are you sure there is something to consider here?

Comment: @bipll, a one-liner if you write it as unreadable awk. If you write it as well-formatted, commented awk (as I've written it as well-formatted, commented bash), it'll still be spread over multiple lines. Similarly, it could be made into a one-liner in bash as well, at a cost of unreadability and unmaintainability -- but that's valuing the wrong things. Terseness is only a virtue when it makes code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @beastx see https://ideone.com/ZPnz16 for an extended version of this (that handles "pairs" that actually have multiple names before a number) handling your "extended input example". (In the future, examples should try to follow [mcve] rules -- the shortest input that exercises all necessary behavior provided with the question up-front; this is turning into what we call a "chameleon question", constantly edited after a correct answer turns out not to meet the OP's true needs; those tend to be frowned on here).

Comment: (That the awk community values one-liners that sacrifice readability in favor of conserving vertical whitespace -- as if that were somehow at a premium -- is something I'll never understand. Aren't [these multi-line versions of the `awk` scripts given by Cyrus and karakfa](https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/aecf9ae69de83573c9a54d37cfa4b654) much easier to understand than the originals?).

Comment: @charles I can't seem to get your solution working. It simply shows an empty screen.

Comment: Yes the formatting and suchlike for asking a question like this has been a new experience for me and the request for a one liner is more for possible future automated usage, but currently full script or one-liner works.

Comment: @beastx, the whole reason I've provided ideone links is so you can *actually see the code work*; see the "stdout" near the bottom of the page -- that's the output of the code when the copy of bash run by ideone.com invoked it. If you have questions about how to make automated usage of a multi-line script, feel free to ask such a question if you can't find it already in the knowledgebase -- there's literally no case where you can use a one-liner but can't use a script.

Answer (score 3):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -F- 'NR%2{p=$1; next} 80<=$1 && $1<=199 {print p,$1}' file

al12t5683 88
al12t5684 100
al12t5686 91
```

**UPDATE**

for the empty line record delimiter

```
$ awk -v RS= '80<=$2 && $2<=199{sub(/-.*/,"",$1); print}' file

al12t5683 88
al12t5684 100
al12t5686 91
```

Comment: Apologies, not used to editing correctly, the input file has extra white spaces, normally every 3rd row, but not always the case, so this seems to break your code

Comment: Your input file format changed a lot, the updated script depends on the record structure, otherwise if the file is not structured consistently you need to fall back to pattern matching.  You didn't mention what happens when there are two text lines followed with one number as in your latest example.

Comment: Karafka, yes looking deeper into the input file along with the lessons learned in asking a question like this has changed the initial quests a bit.

But this single liner does seem to be going in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nle's/-.*//; $n=<>; print "$_ $n" if 80<=$n && $n<=199' inputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With gnu sed

```
sed -E '
N
/\n[8-9][0-9]$/bA
/\n1[0-9]{2}$/!d
:A
s/([^-]*).*\n([0-9]+$)/\1 \2/
' infile
```

Comment: @Anonymous Downvoter Sure sed isn'nt the best tool for this task but I get the espected result. Perhaps you can tell that in a comment to explain.

Comment: My assumption (as someone who got a downvote at about the same time) is that the person was dinging answers they saw as overly complex or hard for readers to follow, since the question was asking for a clean or simple solution. Of course, *if* that was truly their objection, "hard to follow" can be countered by adding comments, a prose description of function, links, &c; I've tried to edit my own answer towards that end.